# Does CQL support the "OR" operator in a WHERE clause?

Tags: cassandra, cql

Are there any limitations or syntactic alternatives in CQL given the constraints around partition and clustering keys while considering to use the OR operator ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According [this link](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/select_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_d35_v2q_xj__synopsis_unique_28), the 'OR' operator is not supported by CQL.

You can only use AND operator with primary key columns (partition key and clustering columns keys).

The 'IN' operator is supported but there are several limitations see [this link](http://mechanics.flite.com/blog/2014/01/08/the-in-operator-in-cassandra-cql/).

But there is a way to query cassandra with less limitations. You can use external tools like Apache drill, Apache Spark, PrestoDB for exemple to query cassandra (and other datasources) with SQL. This tools provide and SQL language to query many différent datasources.

But be careful, this is very dangerous with big data volume if your query is not optimized. But some tools use specific query constraint to run query more efficient (prestoDB optimaze query to use cassandra partition key)

Comment: External link no longer works. :(